# Calling a function to search for an item then delete the item

Tags: python, function, loops, class, methods

I'm adding a function called `remove_item` and within this function it'll call the `find_item` function which are both under a class. `find_item` is used to look for the item and if found it should be removed and return True once removed. Otherwise False.

It can find the item but unable to remove it and I get
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

I tried printing (self.all_toys.name) to see what it has and I get this:
[<**main**.Toy object at 0x00000231EA5C2350>, <**main**.Toy object at 0x00000231EA5C2320>, <**main**.Toy object at 0x00000231EA5C2290>]

Is this the reason why it can't find the value?

I have a count function which works fine which should output the correct number of items after an item has been removed.

```
def find_item(self, find_name):
    for toy_name in self.all_items:
        if toy_name.name.lower() == find_name.lower():
            return toy_name

def remove_item(self, remove):      

    if self.find_toy(remove):
        item_delete = remove
        self.all_toys.remove({item_delete})

        return 'True'
        
    else:
        return 'False'
```

Comment: May be I misunderstood but your remove_toy has statements which are not needed. Your find_toy would either return the toy_name object or None type. In remove_toy you don't need to run find_toy twice. Do this only: `if find_toy(remove): return True else return False`. BTW, in your remove_toy() you are only returning something, not removing.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `self.all_toys.remove({item_delete})`, exactly what do you expect that to mean? In particular, what effect do you expect the `{}` to have?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) That includes both expected and actual output, if it's text that will appear in the terminal. Instead, copy and paste the text, formatted like code; if you need to draw attention to something, write an explanation separately.

Comment: "Is this the reason why it can't find the value?" No; that's what your instances will look like by default. As an aside, though, it would probably be more useful to `return` the boolean values `True` and `False`, rather than strings.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question. In self.all_toys.remove({item_delete}), I'm trying to delete the found toy with variable item_delete contained in self.all_toys using remove().  I tried adding braces to test if it'll find the value.

Answer (score 0):

According to python documentation:

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It
> raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

So you need to implement `__eq__` method in your `Toy` class. Without it python can only delete object by reference.

```
class Toy:
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name


toy_list = [Toy("1"), Toy("2")]
toy_list.remove(toy_list[1])  # delete Toy("2")
toy_list.remove(Toy("1"))  # ValueError
```

You can override default `__eq__` method and compare name attribute.

```
class Toy:
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        return isinstance(__o, Toy) and self.name == __o.name


toy_list = [Toy("1"), Toy("2")]
toy_list.remove(toy_list[1])  # delete Toy("2")
toy_list.remove(Toy("1"))  # delete Toy("1")
print(toy_list)  # []
```

Also, if you implement this method, you can use `in` operator to check if an object is in the array:

```
toy = Toy("1")
if toy in toy_list:
    toy_list.remove(toy)  # delete Toy("1")
```

This will be more reliable, because it eliminates the logical error when checking for being in an array and finding an element to remove use different logic.